# How to paste moves to another object?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have two objects (peoples) and I'm creating a choreography tutorial with them. I make the moves to one of the objects, but is possible copy the keyframes and paste to the another object? There's a way to reflect the moves?

Comment: you need to open the Dopesheet, switch to Action Editor mode, give your animation a name, select your other object and in the Dopesheet scroll in the actions dropdown menu and select the same animation

Comment: You could help the understanding of your question along with a screenshot. It would help us see whether you already have armatures in the scene, etc.